# How do I set the Laravel application database path?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm looking to use a vendor's database directory. I found this in the getMigrationPath function. How do I configure my Laravel app to use a different database directory and subsequently it's subdirectories?

`laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Foundation/Application.php`

```
    /**
     * Get the path to the migration directory.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getMigrationPath()
    {
        return $this->laravel->databasePath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'migrations';
    }
```

Comment: You wouldn't, typically. You'd usually do `php artisan vendor:publish` to *copy* the package's migrations into your `database/migrations` folder for customization.

Comment: They will be my migrations from another repo. I'm not looking to make a copy of them. I will just maintain them from the other repo.

Comment: I don't think this is configurable, for reasons already stated above. You can change the database path at runtime using `app()->useDatabasePath("/path/to/database")` or you can specify the path when you run `artisan migrate --path=/path/to/database/migrations`. That's about it.

Comment: app()->useDatabasePath("/path/to/database") was the solution for me. @miken32 do you want to make it an answer?

Comment: Glad to help, answer posted. (That other answer was ChatGPT nonsense by the way; I flagged it for deletion by mods.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot configure your app's migration directory permanently, but you can change the migration directory at run time in one of two ways:

1. When running a migration from the command line: `artisan migrate --path=/path/to/migrations`
2. From within your application code: `app()->useDatabasePath("/path/to/database")`. Note this is setting the path to the database directory, not the migrations directory. Typically this is something like `/var/www/html/app/database/` and a subdirectory called `migrations` is expected to be present there.